# remove right side quotation date from the quotation order in odoo

Tags: odoo, qweb

I would like to remove the Quotation date and Salesperson which is located right side but I can't find where their reference ids.

Where should I get references, I can't find it in report_saleorder_document

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='col-auto mw-100 mb-2'][4]" position="replace"/>
                  <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-auto mw-100 mb-2'][3]" position="replace"/>
```

the following codes don't work
see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZAtg.jpg

Comment: Which odoo version you are using as the base version has the reference ids under the given label.

Comment: Hi Keval, odoo 11

Comment: Can you post your code here ?

Comment: <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-auto mw-100 mb-2'][4]" position="replace"/>
                  <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-auto mw-100 mb-2'][3]" position="replace"/>